# How can I clean the sound of aplay received by a caputre card

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, ffplay

I am trying to setup my linux desktop to be able to view and listent to the device connected to my capture card. I wrote this 2 liner script to be able to do that however my sound is out of tone and a bit distorted, how could I clean it up?

```
arecord --buffer-time=1 -f cd - | aplay --buffer-time=1 -c 5 -r 48000 -f S16_LE - 2> /dev/null &

ffplay -f video4linux2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -input_format mjpeg /dev/video1 2> /dev/null &
```

I also tried to do that with ffmpeg piped to ffplay and the sound is crystal clear however there is 2-3 seconds delay on the video and sound, is there a way to fix this?

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -thread_queue_size 1024 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video1 -f pulse -i 'Analog Input - USB Video' -r 30 -threads 4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -vsync 1 -async 1 -f matroska - |ffplay -
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try just using `ffplay` for your second approach?

```
ffplay -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 \
  -thread_queue_size 1024 -input_format mjpeg -i /dev/video1 \
  -f pulse -i 'Analog Input - USB Video'`
```

I could be off-base as I'm only familiar with `ffmpeg` and don't personally use `ffplay`, but they share a lot of things (e.g., backend libraries and command line parsing) so I'm hedging this would work.

Also, what do you mean by "there is 2-3 seconds delay on the video and sound"? Are they 2-3 seconds behind what you are physically seeing and hearing? Or are they out of sync by that many seconds?

[addendum]

Not sure if OP is still checking this post, but there is a solution to combine two inputs for ffplay by using an input filtergraph with `movie` and `amovie` filters. The following worked in Windows (despite unacceptably large latency):

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i \
  movie=filename=video="Logitech HD Webcam C310":format_name=dshow:format_opts=rtbufsize=702000k[out0]; \
  amovie=filename=audio="Microphone (HD Webcam C310)":format_name=dshow[out1]
```

Note that this is only for the illustration purpose as `dshow` device can output multiple streams (though the latency is still too bad for real-time use).

The same should be possible in Linux:

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i \
  movie=filename=/dev/video1:format_name=video4linux2:format_opts='framerate=30:video_size=1920x1080:thread_queue_size=1024:input_format=mjpeg'[out0]; \
  amovie=filename='Analog Input - USB Video':format_name=pulse[out1]
```

(Disclaimer: Untested and it may be missing escaping)

The latency may be better in Linux (and with a higher spec'ed PC than mine) so it might be worth a try.

Comment: Unfortuanetely ffplay takes only one input that's why I am starting sound with aplay/ arecord and video with ffplay. Or I can use ffmpeg to just combine them to one source. By delay I mean, I am actually using a nintendo switch, when I press a button it takes 2-3 second for the action to be shown on the screen and the sound 'to be heard', video and sound is synced together but not real time.

Comment: Ah OK. I wasn't aware of the one-input limitation of `ffplay`. Have you tried to use `-c copy` option (at least for the video feed)? You may need to find a format that works with the codecs that inputs uses (which could be a problem on its own)

Comment: @nmousouros - Just FYI, I discovered a way to pull streams from different devices for `ffplay`. I suspect the latency would still be too large for your need, but something else to try.

Comment: I will give it a try when I get home, I suspect that the latency comes from ffmpeg trying to convert them somehow to a supported container " matroska", the -c copy didn't want it really needs a format but with ffplay directly showing my device I get 0 latency, or at least so little that is not noticeable so maybe you way of giving 2 inputs might work